# PHP load as XML in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to load in XML to populate a search box. The code I have works fine with a static xml file, but I need to load in a PHP file to generate a dynamic XML file based on data from a database.

I knwo the PHP file generates the XML as it loads in a browser and the page source shows the correct nodes etc, however when I reference the .php file in my JavaScript it fails to load, or show an error... Using the .xml file (which is a replica of the php output source) it loads fine.

I would like someone to check to see if I am encoding the XML correctly or missing something in my JavaScript... and advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
JS

var myArr = [];
$.ajax({            
     url: "people.php", // change to full path of file on server
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: parseXml,
     complete: setupAC,
     failure: function(data) {
       alert("XML File could not be found");
     }
});

function parseXml(xml){
     $(xml).find("person").each(function(){     
        var thisItem = $(this).find('name').text();
        myArr.push(thisItem);
        alert(thisItem);
     });    
}

PHP

<?php

    include '../../inc_global/connect.php';

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM candidates';  

    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);

    $xmlOutput = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    $xmlOutput .= "<people>\n";

    while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   $xmlOutput .= "<person>\n"; 
   $xmlOutput .= "<name>" . $line['name'] . "</name>\n"; 
   $xmlOutput .= "</person>\n";

}

$xmlOutput .= "</people>\n";

echo $xmlOutput;

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: try removing the `dataType: "xml",` property

Comment: 3nigma - that worked instantly! Thank you for that however I'm not sure why? Does this have something to do with the header ("Content-Type:text/xml") declaration I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put header right before outputting information:

```
....
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  
echo $xmlOutput;
....
```

Fullcode:

```
<?php

    include '../../inc_global/connect.php';

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM candidates';  

    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);

    $xmlOutput = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    $xmlOutput .= "<people>\n";

    while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   $xmlOutput .= "<person>\n"; 
   $xmlOutput .= "<name>" . $line['name'] . "</name>\n"; 
   $xmlOutput .= "</person>\n";

}

$xmlOutput .= "</people>\n";

header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  //<----------- xml header here
echo $xmlOutput;

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what's happening in php pointing your browser to `people.php`.

Anyway I advice you to:

#### drop mysql_ for PDO

As `mysql_` funcs are bad and will prevent from meeting chicks, while [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) helps;

#### use SimpleXML against raw XML

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) helps you structure your code without getting mad in chaining strings.

#### give proper HTTP header to your document

You are generating an XML document, let the browser be aware of that:

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  
echo $xmlOutput;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that the function parseXml(xml) doesn't need any parameter when it is called on success of ajax call. Please note that I haven't tried the code but just a guess is here.